# Can't install TWRP on Note 4

Tags: rooting, twrp, odin, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I'm trying to install **TWRP** ("`openrecovery-twrp-2.8.1.1-trltetmo.img.tar`") on Samsung Galaxy **Note 4 SM-N910F** with Android 5.1.1 . I tried to do it with **Odin** versions v3.09 and v3.10.7 using different USB cables and ports. The process always seems correct: it shows '*ID:COM*' and finishes without errors, showing **green** and ends up resetting the device, but after that I try to boot into '*Download mode*' and after pressing "*volume down*" + *Home* + *Power* it keeps showing the **default recovery**, it doesn't boot on TWRP.

I've uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j5z1iqowo46xwlf/AAAkj-L-243FcKD0krMqsnIWa?dl=0) five screenshots showing what's happening. Here's one of them, showing that apparently everything has worked fine and the device is beeing rebooted:
[image]

PC configuration:

- Windows 7
- Already installed Drivers "*SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.zip*"
  from [here](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117)

Device configuration:

- '*USB debugging*' is enabled
- Security => '*Reactivation lock*' is disabled.

How can I install and boot correctly TWRP?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

/Angel

Comment: Uncheck "Auto-Reboot" in Odin?

Comment: 1. Uncheck auto reboot 2. If your device has a removable battery, remove that and boot into recovery. 3. if not  fastboot reboot them boot into twrp recovery. Reason:  see Odin section last paragraph here https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxynote4qualcomm.html. Also, make sure you are flashing the correct TWRP

Comment: Once you are done, you can use [quick boot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.siriusapplications.quickboot) to launch into TWRP recovery IF you find recovery key combination tricky to handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks you all for your answers. It was a mistake of mine when pressing the key combination. I told I was doing "volume down" + Home + Power, but that's to boot into '*download mode*', to boot into *recovery* the combination is "**volume up**" + Home + Power.

Thanks,

/Angel

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue.
I flashed TWRP using ODIN but my Note4 (N910G) wouldn't boot to recovery.
Then I used TWRP Manager from Playstore (Not the official TWRP application), this had option to boot to recovery , this allowed me to boot to TWRP successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I installed it using odin and it was stuck in recovery booting.

Then I removed the battery and rebooted in recovery and there was a script running that reinstalled stock recovery.

I flashed it once again using odin WITHOUT auto-reboot.

I removed the battery once the flash was done.

Put it back in and used Vol+ + power to boot in TWRP and voilà !

Flashed supersu 2.79 , it patched the root and I'm now fully rooted :)